# file module - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

i know that node.js is relativity new.. so i hope that someone here can really help me.

i want to make a simple server-client program that works on windows 7.

i am having some problem in creating a file module.

i have one file lets call it a.js

```
/* a.js file*/
var net = require('net');
function startServer(port,resourceMap,rootFolder){
//does somthing
}

exports.startServer=startServer;
```

and then another file b.js in the same folder

```
/* b.js file*/
var server = require('*.*\a');
```

for some reason when i try to run the command node b.js
it tells me that it does not recognize the module.

i know that in linux

```
var server = require('./a');
```

should work.
but i searched allot and all the examples that i find are only linux.

i know that it is probably smothing stupid, but i cant seem to find it.

thank you

Comment: Are you talking about Node.js? Jnode seems to be something different entirely. If you are, in Node.js, `var a = require('./a');` etc. should work regardless of platform.

Comment: you are right. i got mixed up...it is node.js
the compiler claims that a is not defined.
don't know why..

Comment: What output do you see on the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you think that this code block is supposed to do:

```
var server = require('*.*\a');
```

Node.js normalizes disk paths between Linux and Windows so using `var server = require('./a');` will work just fine on Windows.

Comment: well.. for some reason the compiler just does not recognize it.
it tells me that a is not defined.
maybe it is the node version that i downloaded? 0.6.3.0?